# How to implement MySQL INSERT Using Route-Controller-Service Structure with Async and Promise?

Tags: mysql, node.js, asynchronous, promise, insert

I'm using a route-controller-service structure to manage a MySQL query. In my controller file, I call the function `getProfileId()` in `displays.service.js` (`displaysService.getProfileId()`).

```
// -------------------------------
// get the thermostat's profile id
// -------------------------------

let getProfileIdResponse;

try {
    getProfileIdResponse = await displaysService.getProfileId(schemaName, slotName, deviceId);
} catch(error) {
    console.log(error);
    return res.status(401).send('Server Error: getProfileId');
}
```

In my services file, I execute the query as follows:

```
function getProfileId(schemaName, slotName, deviceId) {

    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {

        var getDisplayDataResponse;
        link.database = schemaName;

        const pool = mysql.createPool(link);
        const promisePool = pool.promise();

        try {

            getProfileIdResponse = await promisePool.query('SELECT ' + slotName + ' FROM SmartEnergyDevice WHERE DeviceID = ?', [deviceId]);

        } catch(error) {

            console.log(error);
            reject(error);

        } finally {

            resolve(getProfileIdResponse);
        }
    })
}
```

All of this works fine.

Question: what is the correct way to implement a database `INSERT` using this methodology?

INSERT INTO Profiles commandQueue (TargetID) VALUES (1000);